# How to know which List item is tapped using Composable Architecture with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swift-composable-architecture

Given a pretty basic [TCA](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-composable-architecture) `View` with a `List` populated by a `ViewStore`, how to know which cell in the list is tapped? in `onTapGesture`, there is no access to the item, since its a scope above. If you add a `onTapGesture` to the `Text`, it will not trigger when tapping the whole cell.

```
WithViewStore(self.store) { viewStore in
  NavigationView {
    List {
      ForEach(viewStore.state.listItems, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item.title)
      }
    }.onTapGesture {
      print("Tapped row, but no access to item")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Put the `onTapGesture` on the `Text` so there is one on each row

Answer (score 0):

As lorem ipsum mentioned in the comments, the `onTapGesture` is in the wrong place.  It should be associated with the Text.  This is how I would do it using your current code:

```
      List {
          ForEach(viewStore.state.listItems, id: \.self) { item in
             Text(item.title)
               .onTapGesture {
                  viewStore.send(.itemSelected(item))
               }
          }
      }
```

In your `AppState` struct you should add a variable to hold the current selection:

```
var selectedItem: ItemType // you haven't provided a definition, but this should be a class, not a struct
```

In your `AppAction`  enum you add the case:

```
public enum SimpleAction {
    case itemSelected(ItemType)
...
}
```

In your reducer you add (inside your switch):

```
switch action {
        case let . itemSelected(item):
           // either assign as 
           state.selectedItem = item
           // or do the needful as you require
    }
```

That said, I would probably enumerate the list to get an index and send the Int index to the reducer instead of the item itself. If anything is unclear (to anyone), please comment and I'll update my response.

Comment: I would also add padding around the Text View to make it easier to recognize a tap. Everything you are asking for is doable.